# Is it possible to have a tilable full chest detection in this scenario?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a 200+ item sorter.
Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

It is a standard tilable sorter with a hopper pipe on top to feed the items.
Above it there is the ceiling that is also the floor of the level above (under the bottom chest there is the ceiling of the level beneath).
The top chest is currently checked by a comparator going to a redstone lamp.
This means that as soon as there is an item in there, the lamp turns on (and the 2 next to it, but I can live with that).

Is there a way to make the lamp turn on when there are more items in the chest (ideally when it is full) and keep the whole thing tileable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - using a 15 signal strength detector utilizing the quirk of comparators that when reading a container through a solid block, they output signal strength corresponding to fullness of the chest, unless the block receives power level 15 (when they start outputting that signal strength 15).

The barrels are *empty*. Utilizing hoppers instead of barrels will be a bit more expensive and less lag-friendly but will allow easier access to the second row of chests.

[image]

A slightly worse w.r.t. to lag, but much more compact way with a quirk that it only activates once the 'back' hopper fills up, not the chest (might be desirable as it will only fill up if *all* chests are full; if someone empties all chests except of the top one, the prior method would falsely announce the slice is full): Item frames can be fit into the same block space as comparators, and without items in them they'll produce the same 'empty' signal to the comparator reading them through the block. In this case barrels are only used as extra storage space and can be omitted (a doublechest in that location wouldn't be openable.) It costs an extra row of hoppers (you can't read the filter hoppers of the overflow-proof sorter, because *being overflow-proof*, they are never full!) but you get a very neat isolation of the redstone-heavy "back-end" from the neat storage space with indicators close to their respective slices and no blocks obstructing access to the chests.

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting this answer despite not being able to use the solution (other constraints, that I have not listed to avoid making the question too messy, get in the way). After looking more deeply into this comparator behaviour, it really seems I have no choice.